# Dual-Virtualization vs. Dual-Boot and Virtualization with GPU passtrhough

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, dualboot, dual-gpu

I recently watched this [SomeOrdinaryGamers video](https://odysee.com/@SomeOrdinaryGamers:a/i-finally-built-my-dream-pc!:6?r=FZ6wz6uUgWZETZGn2ikkjcx3vRMB9vUp) that teaches how to passthrough a GPU to a VM. Around 26:15 of said video he mentions a way to virtualize Windows AND boot it from the drive, but not how to do it.

I've been researching about this and found this question [Dual-Virtualization vs. Dual-Boot vs. Single-Virtualization](https://superuser.com/questions/419236/dual-virtualization-vs-dual-boot-vs-single-virtualization) that talks about another way to go about this, which is basically having both Linux and Windows as VMs on a light weight host OS. However, much of it kinda goes over my head.

The idea would be to have 2 SSDs (one for each OS) and 2 GPUs (an AMD for Linux and an Nvidia for Windows). Linux would be the "main OS". From that I would like to be able both run Windows as a VM and boot it by itself for activities such as gaming.

Which method would best accomplish this task? What would be the drawbacks? Is there a beginner friendly tutorial on how to do each of this methods?

Also, would the Dual-Boot + Virtualization method present any problems regarding the Windows license? I've read that Windows recognizes the VM as a separate machine and would therefore deactivate the license. If so, are there workarounds for this?

Edit: Just to clarify, what I want to be able to do is use Linux as my daily driver and have a Dual-Boot with Windows for when I need it (work, gamming, etc.) but also be able to run the same Windows install within a VM with GPU passthrough in Linux for convenience. Either that or the "Dual-Virtualization" method I mentioned, whichever would be more efficient.

Comment: 2 SSDs would not be required. One SSD will do(with GPT/EFI partion,one+ for linux and 1+ for windows.  2 Graphics cards I can see the need for. Either that or needing to edit PCIe parameter depending on intended bootand reboots between switching OS. As totutorials, Ionly bookmarked many years old ones, but I am very curious to see the answers to this great question.

Comment: "Dual virtualization" is called "nested virtualization" in all three major hypervisors.   There are a literal ton of websites that explain how to run a Windows VM within Windows.  However, what you describe does not require nested virtualization, you can handle your goal with just a single layer of hardware virtualization.

Comment: Just to clarify, what I want to be able to do is use Linux as my daily driver and have a Dual-Boot with Windows for when I need it (work, gamming, etc.) but also be able to run the same Windows install within a VM with GPU passthrough in Linux for convenience. Either that or the "Dual-Virtualization" method I mentioned, whichever would be more efficient.